# Agregar un numero con insert con determinados par de indices

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente lista en python:

```
Lista= [100, 25,65, [54,25, [96, 21,47]] ,52]
```

Agrega el número 65 en el índice `[3][2]`.

Pude agregar hasta el índice 3, usé append. Hice lo siguiente pero con el método insert:

```
Lista3 = [100, 25, [54,25, [96, 21,47]] ,52]

Lista3.insert(3, (65))

print(Lista3)
```

Llego al índice 3 pero no sé cómo escribir para llegar a `[3][2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Las listas de Python funcionan como listas en un papel, solo que en vez que contar desde 1, se cuenta desde 0. Toma de ejemplo esta lista:

0. item-0
1. item-1
2. 0. item-2-0
   1. item-2-1
   2. 0. item-2-2-0
      1. item-2-2-1
3. item-3

Si querés acceder a un indice especifico de una sublista, primero hay que acceder a dicha sublista. En el caso de la lista 2-2:

- accedemos a la primera sublista `lista[2]`
- usando la lista obtenida accedemos al tercer item `lista[2][2]`, que es la sublista de la sublista.

Ahora, tenés la lista a la que buscas insertarle el valor, entonces, si querés insertar algo en la posición 1, hacés `.insert(1, valor)`

**Código completo**

```
lista[2][2].insert(1, valor)
```

O, en tu escenario:

```
lista[3].insert(2, 65)
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Error al correr el programa]

Manda error. No será que hay que declarar el objeto con atributos con método constructor?

Comment: La proxima, te recomiendo dejarme un comentario avisando y editar la pregunta como mencionan más arriba. Si no, el sistema no me notifica. Pero en relación al error, no estás accediendo correctamente. Te recomiendo que escribas esa lista en forma de lista "común" y uses eso de referencia para escribir el código (es lo que hice en mi respuesta). También te recomiendo que releas la explicación que te di y, lo más importante, hacelo paso a paso, anotate cada paso en un papel si es necesario. Que te vaya bien!

Comment: Otra cosa, el método insert dice "agrega, en la posición x, el valor que estoy pasandote", eso significa que tenés que obtener la sublista y aplicarle el insert pasando la posición x como argumento.